# Android SharedPreferences not saving on some devices

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a weird problem.  Saving my user's settings to SharedPreferences works fine for 80% of our users.  But for the other 20%, the preferences are not saved.

I have test devices with the same version of android installed, and it works fine.  I also have old and newer devices to test with.  I simply cannot re-create the issue.

Does anyone have any idea what could be happening here?  Is there a setting that some users may have set on their phone that prevents the saving to the preferences file?

I am lost.  Please throw out any ideas.

My code is very straightforward… here is an example.

```
if(mSwitchSound.isChecked()){
            editor.putBoolean(Preferences.IS_SOUND_ON, true);
        } else {
            editor.putBoolean(Preferences.IS_SOUND_ON, false);
        }
        editor.commit();
```

Thank You.

Comment: Could the users be moving/saving the data to the SD card, via the App Info section of the Application Manager settings menu?? Android says these are distinctly different storage methods, but you asked for ideas,...

Comment: is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

I must say that if Shared Preferences is working one one device no matter what the Android version is as i have not just tested Android phones but Google Tv, Android Smart PC's etc. So, it should work on all however if you are getting this issue what i can guess is that the object may be static and that on some devices the objects are destroyed. or the issue is somewhere else. Ask your manager to give you the log for the Exceptions generated that the users have reported and post the log if there is any. Then we might be able to help

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Junior Android Developer and I've currently been facing the same issue (app crashes due to null returns). I developed an uber-eats type app but for some reason, some devices cant save into the shared preferences. Some devices of the same brand and model would present this issue while others (of the same brand and model) wouldn't. a friend of mine mentioned that at his company he has faced the same issue, he mentioned that this may be caused due to the different configuration of ROM on each device. Therefore he only develops for specific devices.

Unfortunately i haven't found a fix for this either, however my work around it is to create a configuration file in the phones internal storage. I used javascript object notation (JSON) to structure my configuration file. I then used GSON to serialize and deserialize my JSON to a java model class. Hope this helps.